# XML overriding entire file if I try to over ride the single tag

Tags: c#, xml

I have an install-able .NET application that prints tickets by periodically checking for updates on a remote server. The application needs to send the current app_id, and last_called (time) to get the updates since the time application last called.

Here's the XML where store the settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PrinterSettings>
      <Printer>
        <Printer1></Printer1>
      </Printer>
      <last_called></last_called>
      <app_id></app_id>
 <PrinterSettings>
```

The application runs every few seconds the job, an then updates the XML with the latest last_called (time), with the following code:

```
var xe1 = new XmlDocument();
xe1.Load("Xmlfilepath");
xe1.SelectSingleNode("/PrinterSettings/last_called").InnerText = sale_modified_time;
xe1.Save("Xmlfilepath");
```

While the application seems to be running fine the first day or so, It frequently gets emptied to a blank document - and the application fails to run further.

How can I fix this?

Another note, to run the application, I set the file permissions to "Allow All" on windows.

Comment: What do you mean by overriding the entire xml file? Does it then only consist of the last_modified node?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you give a reproducible example with input and incorrect output and tell us what the expected output is?

Comment: There is no content in that file after successfully running for few days.

Comment: I need to take the values from that xml file like location id and printer1 details at the staring of the program and i need to update the lasst_modifed value at the end of the program. This will run  in a loop for every 15 sec

Comment: We can't reproduce that, though.  If I run it a million times with the same input, it's not going to give a different output.  Something caused it to break - likely unexpected input.  What that was or what caused it is impossible to guess.

Comment: I think you should add some code to prevent or at least detect the writing of an empty xmldocument. Maybe check the count of childnodes within the document after loading and before writing the file. If its not that, maybe another process overrides your file.

Comment: Code you've provided is pretty deterministic, and it can't empty your file by itself. Probably there is some side factor preventing normal saving of `XmlDocument`. You can surround `xe1.Save` with `try/catch` block and in `catch` handle exception and write its text some log file.

Comment: I am storing the logs in  a text file,and I did not found such exception while updating the file.

Answer (score 1):

I am starting to think that someone else is emptying your file. The Load() method of your XmlDocument does take a stream as a parameter. Maybe use a FileStream to your file and set its FileShare to None. This way, noone should be able to override your file.

Kepp in mind, that you have to set the streams Position property to 0 before reading/writing (loading/saving) your XML

Comment: I will try to implement this logic.

Comment: I don't think somebody is emptying the file.  Instead I think there is another thread that need to be synchronized to the current process so there aren't conflicts.  If you are on a network using group policy if the server doesn't return the proper credentials you may not be allowed to open the file.

Comment: @jdweng: Thats what i meant by 'someone'. I did some experiments and the XmlDocument wont allow loading/saving of documents that do not contain a single node